# unit test case for raise error in ruby rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a method which would check if the argument contains any value, if not it would raise error which would be rescued so that it will be notified and continues the execution.

```
def check_value(options)
  if options[:id].blank?
    raise "An id must be provided"
  end
  options[:url] = generate_url_and_save()
  save_without_issue(options[:url])
rescue ex
  report_error(ex)
end
```

What would be test case for the scenario of options[:id] becomes blank.
I tried the below code but not sure whether it is the right way to do it

```
context '#check_value' do
  it 'should raise error if id is blank' do
    expect{subject.check_value({:id=> ''}}.to raise_error
  end
end
```

Comment: Are these codes runnable? I guess they should be `def check_value(options)` and `expect{subject.check_value({:id=> ''}}.to raise_error`

Comment: Yeah.. You are right.. its was just a typo

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's "right". If you wanted to check the message raised with the error you could use `raise_error('An id must be provided')`.  See https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-8/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher for more information.